# Как одну строку разбить на n количество строк

Tags: javascript

Имеется строка, например

```
"0J3QsNC/0YDQsNGB0L3Qvikg0JfQtNC10YHRjCDQvdC40YfQtdCz0L4g0L3QtdGCIQ=="
```

Нужно разбить ее на `n` количество строк для отправки ее чанками.
Нашел такой вариант:

```
"0J3QsNC/0YDQsNGB0L3Qvikg0JfQtNC10YHRjCDQvdC40YfQtdCz0L4g0L3QtdGCIQ==".match(/.{1,20}/g);
```

В результат получаю то что нужно

```
0: "0J3QsNC/0YDQsNGB0L3Q"

1: "vikg0JfQtNC10YHRjCDQ"

2: "vdC40YfQtdCz0L4g0L3Q"

3: "tdGCIQ=="
```

Но вместо **20** мне нужно установить переменную, которую в данном выражении использовать нельзя.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: "нужно установить переменную, которую в данное выражение вставить нельзя" - почему нельзя?

Comment: String.match(/.{x,n}/g)  - в данном выражении x,n принимают только числовые значения

Comment: А разве вы хотите установить нечисловую длину?

Comment: При объявлении переменной, которая содержит число, функция не срабатывает

Comment: Приведите это в вопросе, вероятно вы просто неправильно составляете строчку с переменной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и с переменной:

```js
function splitByLength(str, length) {
  return str.match(RegExp(`.{1,${length}}`, 'gu'));
}

console.log(splitByLength('1234567890', 3)); // [ '123', '456', '789', '0' ]
console.log(splitByLength('1234567890', 4)); // [ '1234', '5678', '90' ]
console.log(splitByLength('1234567890', 5)); // [ '12345', '67890' ]
```